# How to implement type to Object's value in Typescript(Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to implement type to object's value. The problem is that target object has to have another type. The object is Angular's Router.

What I want to do is.

```
const object: Type = [{ // <-- I have to use Type here.
  otherkey: value,
  data: { // <-- I want to implement type here.
   a: 1,
   b: 'hello'
     }
}]

interface TypeForData {
   a: number;
   b: string;
}
----------------------
// in library's .d.ts file
export declare Type{
  otherkey: ...;
  [data: string]:any;
}[]
```

I tried these solution.

1. extend Type.
2. cast value(object).

1.extend Type

```
import { Type } from 'somewhere'
interface TypeForData extends Type{
    a: number;
    b: string;
}[]
then implement to variable. but doesn't work well.
```

2.cast value(object).

```
const object: Type = [{ 
  otherkey: value,
  data: <TypeForData> { 
   a: 1,
   b: 'hello'
     }
}]
but CLI doesn't show error even I assign different type value.
```

I'm really happy if I could get solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
interface TypeForData {
   a: number;
   b: string;
}

var someData: TypeForData;

var obj = {
    someData
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I helps me a lot! I think I works. but In my situation I have to make many variables, It suite for me not to make many variables.

Comment: Well, you can turn `const object` into a class, that is `class ObjectName`. Because everything in JS is an object anyway and then scoped those properties into that class. So you would have something like `class ObjectName { someData: TypeForData; otherKey;}`